# How to trigger HTTP request using SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, httprequest, httpresponse

I have an URL that returns English translation for any word.

Now I would like to trigger that link using pure SQL Server.

I get an error, and I need your help to fix it with me.

Here is my attempt:

```
-- Enable 'Ole Automation Procedures'
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
EXEC sp_configure 'Ole Automation Procedures', 1;
RECONFIGURE;

DECLARE @object INT;
DECLARE @return INT;
DECLARE @valid INT;
DECLARE @output NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @valid = 0;

-- Create the XMLHTTP object
EXEC @return = sp_OACreate 'Microsoft.XMLHTTP', @object OUTPUT;
IF @return = 0
BEGIN
    -- Open the connection
    EXEC @return = sp_OAMethod @object, 'open', NULL, 'GET', 'https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=en&tl=ar&dt=t&q=hello', false;

    IF @return = 0
    BEGIN
        -- Send the request
        EXEC @return = sp_OAMethod @object, 'send';

        IF @return = 0
        BEGIN
            -- Get the response
            --EXEC @return = sp_OAMethod @object, 'send', NULL, '', 'timeout_in_milliseconds';
            --EXEC @return = sp_OAGetProperty @object, 'responseText', @output OUTPUT;

            -- Send the request with a longer timeout (e.g., 10 seconds)
            EXEC @return = sp_OAMethod @object, 'send', NULL, '', 10000;  -- 10 seconds timeout

            IF @return = 0
            BEGIN
                -- Get the response
                EXEC @return = sp_OAGetProperty @object, 'responseText', @output OUTPUT;
                PRINT @return;

                IF @return = 0
                BEGIN
                    -- Extract the status code from the response
                    DECLARE @statusCode INT;
                    EXEC sp_OAMethod @object, 'status', @statusCode OUTPUT;

                    IF @statusCode = 200
                    BEGIN
                        SET @valid = 1;
                    END;
                END;
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                -- Handle the error here, for example:
                PRINT 'Error sending HTTP request';
            END;

        END;
    END;

    -- Destroy the object
    EXEC sp_OADestroy @object;
END;

-- Disable 'Ole Automation Procedures'
EXEC sp_configure 'Ole Automation Procedures', 0;
RECONFIGURE;

IF @valid = 1
    PRINT 'valid'
ELSE
    PRINT 'invalid';
```

Do you know what the problem is, and how to solve it?

**Note**: I need to do the same topic using pure SQL Server

Comment: *DON'T*. Especially not with this 30-year old code. Why do you think you need this?

Comment: SQL Server is a relational database, don't try and make it do tasks best suited to an application or scripting framework.

Comment: All SQL Server supported versions have a Machine Learning Services feature that allows you to use Python or R libraries for data science purposes. That includes translation, text processing, sentiment analysis and similar things. If you want to make translation calls in general, the database is the wrong place

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm not adhering to this code. all I need to accomplish is to trigger translation URL from SQL server using any way, and of course, preferably the newest.

Comment: If you "must" do this is SQL Server (again **strongly** not recommended) then you could use CLR. You would be far better off doing this in your application/middle ware.

Comment: Use `sp_execute_external_script` or on Azure use `sp_invoke_external_rest_endpoint`. Or use SQLCLR at a pinch if you are on an older version. Another options is to create a SQL agent job in Powershell that does this. It's a single line of code.

Comment: The very idea is wrong, not just the code. Network calls take a long time compared to a database transaction which means they *block* that transaction, keeping locks for a lot longer and the chance of deadlocks or blocking other connections. Executing 1 translation request for every row in a 5000 row table means 5000 slow requests.

Comment: Why don't you make this call from a *client* application or eg a Python script? Why the database? You aren't just making a single HTTP call, you're trying to call a Google API that requires authentication. This means you need to log in first, get a token and construct a request with the proper JSON payload and HTTP headers. That's easy to do in a client application with a language like Python - login once and make the requests. You may even be able to batch multiple requests together. There may be ready-made packages that do this for you too

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Something like this seem to work:

```sql
-- Enable 'Ole Automation Procedures'
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
EXEC sp_configure 'Ole Automation Procedures', 1;
RECONFIGURE;

-- Create the XMLHTTP object
DECLARE @authHeader NVARCHAR(64)
,   @contentType NVARCHAR(64)
,   @postData NVARCHAR(2000)
,   @responseText NVARCHAR(2000)
,   @responseXML NVARCHAR(2000)
,   @ret INT
,   @status NVARCHAR(32)
,   @statusText NVARCHAR(32)
,   @token INT
,   @url NVARCHAR(256);

SELECT  @contentType = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
,   @postData = 'client=gtx&sl=en&tl=ar&dt=t&q=hello'
,   @url = 'https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single'
--, @authHeader = 'BASIC 0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF';
-- Open the connection.
EXEC @ret = sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP', @token OUT;
IF @ret <> 0 RAISERROR('Unable to open HTTP connection.', 10, 1);

-- Send the request.
EXEC @ret = sp_OAMethod @token, 'open', NULL, 'POST', @url, 'false';
--EXEC @ret = sp_OAMethod @token, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Authentication', @authHeader;
EXEC @ret = sp_OAMethod @token, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Content-type', @contentType;
EXEC @ret = sp_OAMethod @token, 'send', NULL, @postData;

-- Handle the response.
EXEC @ret = sp_OAGetProperty @token, 'status', @status OUT;
EXEC @ret = sp_OAGetProperty @token, 'statusText', @statusText OUT;
EXEC @ret = sp_OAGetProperty @token, 'responseText', @responseText OUT;

-- Show the response.
PRINT 'Status: ' + @status + ' (' + @statusText + ')';
PRINT 'Response text: ' + @responseText;

-- Close the connection.
EXEC @ret = sp_OADestroy @token;
IF @ret <> 0 RAISERROR('Unable to close HTTP connection.', 10, 1);


-- Disable 'Ole Automation Procedures'
EXEC sp_configure 'Ole Automation Procedures', 0;
RECONFIGURE;
```

But as other's have mentioned, you shouldn't use these methods because they're brittle, leak resources and leads to a lot of downvotes on SO.